# No entiendo porque me sale este error 1136?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

```
Executing:
INSERT INTO `bdaeropuerto`.`tb_hangars` 
    (`Clave`, `Aeropuerto`, `Capacidad`, `Tipo`, 
    `Aerolinea`, `Estatus`, `Aeropuertos_Id`, `Aviones_Id`, `Empleados_Id`)
 VALUES ('fdbgdf', 'dbdvd', '12', 'bkh', 'kbkb', 'kbkb', '1', '1', '2');
```

> ERROR 1136: 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `bdaeropuerto`.`tb_hangars` 
    (`Clave`, `Aeropuerto`, `Capacidad`, `Tipo`, 
    `Aerolinea`, `Estatus`, `Aeropuertos_Id`, `Aviones_Id`, `Empleados_Id`) 
VALUES ('fdbgdf', 'dbdvd', '12', 'bkh', 'kbkb', 'kbkb', '1', '1', '2')
```

ese es el Trigger

```
DELIMITER @ 
CREATE TRIGGER triggerInsertar before INSERT ON tb_hangars 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO bitacora_hangares 
       values(
         new.Clave, new.Capacidad, new.Tipo,
         new.Aerolinea, new.Estatus,
         new.Aeropuertos_Id, new.Aviones_Id,
         new.Empleados_Id, curdate(), 'Agregado'
       );
    END;
@ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Si Son Datos Metidos por ninguna tabla no por consulta !!

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura de la tabla ”tb_hangars”

Answer (score 3):

Si bien la consulta es de hace dos años, recientemente tuve que buscar justamente el motivo por el cual me salía este error.

Encontré que el error (en mi caso) se daba por lo siguiente:

Estaba intentando ingresar un dato menos, en una inserción

```
INSERT INTO miTabla (id_hora, nombre, fecha, horaentrada, horasalida, estado,
 tareas_realizadas, codigo) VALUES (NULL, "Pedro", "2020-02-12", 
 "08:00", "17:00", "Ruptura de ladrillos", "A9LLE442" );
```

Me estaba faltando el valor del dato "estado".

Un modo de verificarlo es revisando que la cantidad de datos y los campos (columnas) sean los mismos.

El uso de NULL como valor del id autoincremental, evita que arroje error. Es totalmente indistinto ingresarlo de este modo, que no agregarlo a la sentencia. Sólo lo puse como ejemplo.

La sentencia que funcionó fue:

```
INSERT INTO miTabla (id_hora, nombre, fecha, horaentrada, horasalida, estado,
 tareas_realizadas, codigo) VALUES (NULL, "Pedro", "2020-02-12", 
 "08:00", "17:00", "TERMINADO", "Ruptura de ladrillos", "A9LLE442" );
```

Sin el campo incremental sería así:

```
INSERT INTO miTabla (nombre, fecha, horaentrada, horasalida, estado, 
 tareas_realizadas, codigo) VALUES ("Pedro", "2020-02-12", "08:00", "17:00",
 "TERMINADO", "Ruptura de ladrillos", "A9LLE442" );
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la esta respuesta tan buena, me dio el mismo error y me faltaba una columna

Answer (score 1):

El id o clave como lo nombraste el primer campo seguramente es un valor autoincrementable, se supone que tratas de insertar un campo nuevo no actualizandolo.

Tienes que omitir el campo que este definido como incrementable en la estrucutura de tu tabla.

Ejemplo, si en mi tabla tengo definido `Id` como incrementable y lo agrego a mi script para inserción obtendré el error que comentas:

```
INSERT INTO  `myDatabase`.`Usuarios` (`Id` , `Name` , `Message`)
VALUES (1,  'Elenasys',  'Working on Python');
```

Lo correcto serìa omitir el campo incrementable:

```
INSERT INTO  `myDatabase`.`Usuarios` (`Name` , `Message`)
VALUES ('Elenasys',  'Working on Python');
```

---

Es error también puede ocurrir si se tiene un Trigger en la tabla que se desea insertar y ese trigger tiene otra instrucción de inserción sin coincidencias de columnas y valores, también provoca el error:

> "Column count doesn't match value count at row ".

Comment: pues el unico dato que es autoincremental es el Id pero ese campo no inserto ningun dato. es mas es el primer campo pero no intento insertar un dato porque se que es autoincremental

Comment: De casualidad usas un trigger que se activa al insertar?

Comment: Pues las columnas int son la de  Capacidad, Aerolinea, Estatus, Aeropuertos_Id, Aviones_Id, Empleados_Id el resto son Varchar!!

Comment: Si estoy usando uno!!

Comment: Upps pato, revisa mi actualizaciòn.

Comment: ese es el Trigger

DELIMITER @

CREATE TRIGGER triggerInsertar before INSERT ON tb_hangars
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO bitacora_hangares values(new.Clave,new.Capacidad,new.Tipo,new.Aerolinea,new.Estatus,
    new.Aeropuertos_Id,new.Aviones_Id,new.Empleados_Id,curdate(),'Agregado');

END;
@
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

Me paso el mismo error con esta consulta:

```
-- insertar todos los registros de la tabla personas hacia la tabla tmppersonas
-- pero solo los que tengan correo de hotmail
insert into tmppersonas
select * from personas
where correo like '%hotmail%';
```

Resulta que mi tabla de origen (personas) tenia una columna demás, tuve que borrar esa columna y ya no me salió el error y pude hacer el `insert` de todos los datos de la otra tabla.

Pues se puede insertar siempre y cuando tengan la misma estructura de origen como el de destino.

Esa fue mi solución para el error en mi caso, espero ayudar en algo y a otro que le este pasando lo mismo y no se haya dado cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también tenia el mismo error.
Pasa que me lo daba por que la tabla donde estaba insertando datos me le faltaba una columna.

Intente de la manera que dice el amigo Jorgesys, quitándole la fila autoincrement y el error ya no me lo daba, pero cuando hacia varios insert a la misma tabla en un while, me daba el  error de la columna Primaria duplicada. Entonces este metodo no me servía para eso, pero si solucionaba el problema, si es solo un insert el que realizaras.

Como dije al inicio, mi problema se debía a que me faltaba una columna en la estructura de mi tabla, Pues hice un import de una base de datos de mi trabajo a la cual le faltaba esa columna, y bueno revisando bien, la estructura de mi tabla y lo que inserto